# rendered partial x.jade is interpreted as html in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pug

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/some.jade',  controller: myAppController}).      
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'
  });
}]);
```

The above code loads the `some.jade` partial, but treats it like `html` thus `h1 try me` which should be rendered as `<h1> try me </h1>` is simply rendered as plain text `h1 try me`

Edit: backend

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon()); 
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.get('/', function(req,res){

    //res.send('hi');
    res.render('login', { title: 'Express' });

});
```

Comment: what does your backend look like?

Comment: put up the express part in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the .jade extension and add this to your express config.

```
app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render('partials/' + name);
});
```

Comment: nothing shows up when i do that. The file `some` does not load at all.

Comment: Try it with the express route added.

Comment: I did. nothing's happened so far. no difference :(

Comment: perfect. u were spot on. Its working with the addition of the above code. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/some.jade',  controller: myAppController})`

should be like this if the jade file is 'some.jade' :

`when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/some',  controller: myAppController})`